# How to create new user on Azure AD using Native App C# XAML?

Tags: c#, rest, azure, graph

How to create new user on Azure AD using Native App C# XAML?

Im reading this reference but I don't how to use the code.
Does anyone here have a sample C# code using windows store dev.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#BasicoperationsonusersCreateusers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find the **Azure Active Directory Graph Client Library** easier to use for this.

You will first have to configure the application in Azure AD and give the application permissions to the Azure AD Graph.

Then, you can use the **Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL)** and the **Azure AD Graph Client Library** in your code to authenticate to Azure AD and programmatically add the user.

There's too much to try and cover in this context, but I show how to do this and more at http://rickrainey.com/2015/02/21/introducing-the-azure-ad-graph-api/

Comment: I tried it site it was very useful for me to use the adal, but unfortunately i cant make the graph api work on windows store app. I can make it work for the console just like your example but not on c# xaml windows store app. I hope you can add new section in that blog teaching us more on making it possible. Thanks a lot and we hope Rick Rainey, there will be more people like you who really help.

Comment: I think there is a Windows Store App example in the Azure AD Samples repository on GitHub.

Comment: Here is a Graph API sample for Windows Store Apps. Not sure what issue you're runing into but hopefully this gives you some hints. https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/NativeClient-WindowsStore